# "deleted recent questions"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

There's a link at the bottom of the questions tab on a user's profile page that reads "deleted recent question". That doesn't seem like correct English; it should say "recently deleted questions".

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the phrasing is awkward, but technically they mean different things. "Deleted recent questions" are questions posted recently that have been deleted. "Recently deleted questions" are questions that were deleted recently, no matter how old they were. I think the former is how the page actually works, so "recently deleted questions" would be wrong, but they should come up with a better way to phrase it. In any case, this is already reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/change-no-deleted-recent-answers-questions-to-no-recently-deleted-answers-que)

Comment: Ah. Interesting. If this is the intention, then the text in the URL that I *had* in my question should probably be changed also, for those who look at this sort of thing. Hopefully more correct England (Intended) grammar will be implemented sometime soon.